# Get AWS EC2 instance name tag from inside the instance using bash

Tags: amazon-ec2

How to get EC2 instance name using bash? `hostname` returning IP address, but I need a value of tag `name` of the current instance.

Comment: No unless you use AWS CLI or other API to get it. BTW, `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/` will show all the local instance meta data, but not the tag name.

Comment: Are you talking about `aws ec2 describe-tags`? If so then is there a way to allow `DescribeTags operation` for any who log in through ssh? We are using standard ssh keys, not `pem` keys provided by AWS, and I'm getting the error `aws ec2 describe-tags

An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeTags operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.`

Comment: You need a give describe tag capabilities from the IAM console to the API key you use.

Comment: @BogdanDubyk grant permission to the instance role to describe tags.  If your instance doesn't have an IAM instance role, it will need one.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot is there a way to grant permissions to all instances. For example, granting it to base AMI? The reason is that I need to run the same bash script in all instances, and get correct name depends on the instance, and adding permissions to each instance is not a good solution

Comment: There is no concept of an instance having any AWS service permissions, apart from [IAM roles for EC2 Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html), which provide instances with a simple way to access a set of automatically-generated, automatically-refreshed temporary IAM credentials that can perform whatever access whatever services you allow in the role's policies.  Best practice is for all instances to have a role, because this provides a secure mechanism for code to access services without storing any credentials on the instance itself.